# user profile redirect in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

####.htaccess file#######

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u([a-z0-9]+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/aydeslis/domains/*******/.htpasswd/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthName "Site in maintenance"
require valid-user
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
```

I am trying to redirect users to a PHP file that shows a user profile the URL would look like this
domain.com/u/user.php?username=[Username] and would be typed into the URL bar like domain.com/u/[username]. would be much appreciated if someone could help me out.

Comment: How does the actual url look like?

Comment: domain.com/u/[username]

Answer (score 0):

According to your url `domain.com/u/[username]` there are slashes missing in your regex.

```
RewriteRule ^u([a-z0-9]+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
//           ^
```

Comment: ? can you show me what that would look like as a whole

Comment: Thats not to hard to google, or even to guess: `/u/`